# JS regex - How to capture the following data set?

Tags: javascript, regex

3 examples of data I am trying match between the quotes:

```
"http://server1.hostname.com/N3234/top=1;level=10;now?"
"http://server133.hostname.com/N34/top=13;level=4;now?"
"http://server99.hostname.com/N112/top=6;level=2;now?"
```

I would like the regex to match:

```
"top=1;level=10;now?"
"top=13;level=4;now?"
"top=6;level=2;now?"
```

My thoughts where that I could say something like

```
/http:\/\/server\d]\.[\w+]\.com/N\d+\/(.*);now?/
```

some additional questions..

Is it correct assume text that I want to match or excude should be exclude like `[^http://]` or what is the right way to do it?

Is `(.*)` the correct method to capture that data I am looking for?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but would'nt [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/y7TBH/) be a lot simpler ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to match the whole thing before it if you're just interested in the data at the end.

```
/top=(\d+);level=(\d+);now/
```

That's all you need. The resulting match array will have the relevant part in index 0, and each of the two numbers in indices 1 and 2.

Comment: I only need that part but I need to validate that server.hostname is part of the input data.